# Why am I getting 'Uncaught TypeError' error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I generated my carousel again according to selected category as below example but after I clicked on my carousel than it gave me this error

[image]
`plugin.js:1132` is start of my [lightgallery plugin](https://github.com/sachinchoolur/lightGallery/) and I'm using this gallery with cycle2.

but there is something that I've to tell you is when I use lightgallery with this path:

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightgallery/1.3.9/js/lightgallery.min.js
```

I don't give any error ([demo](http://codepen.io/cowardguy/pen/mmmNOR)) - but if I use with this path:

```
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/lightgallery@1.3.5,lg-fullscreen@1.0.1,lg-hash@1.0.1,lg-pager@1.0.1,lg-share@1.0.1,lg-thumbnail@1.0.1,lg-video@1.0.1,lg-autoplay@1.0.1,lg-zoom@1.0.3
```

than it give me a this error and I have to use with this because this version include all features what I need.

and my js

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function generateSlider() {
    $(".mySlideShow").cycle({
      next: "#single-right",
      log: false,
      fx: "fade",
      caption: ".cycle-caption",
      captionTemplate: "{{title}}",
      pauseOnHover: true,
      pager: "#single-pager",
      pagerTemplate: "<a href='#'><img class=lazyload data-src={{exthumbimage}} width=60 height=60></a>",
      prev: "#single-left",
      slides: "a[data-hidden='false']"
    });
  }

  generateSlider();

  $(".filter li").on("click", function() {
    var activeId = $(this).attr("id");
    if (activeId == "show-all") {
      $("a").attr("data-hidden", "false");
    } else {
      $("a").attr("data-hidden", "true");
      $("a[data-id = '" + activeId + "']").attr("data-hidden", "false");
    }
    $(".mySlideShow").cycle("destroy");
    generateSlider();
  });

  $(" .mySlideShow").lightGallery({
    exThumbImage: "data-exthumbimage",
    download: false,
    thumbnail: true,
    loadYoutubeThumbnail: true,
    youtubeThumbSize: "default",
    loadVimeoThumbnail: true,
    vimeoThumbSize: "thumbnail_medium"
  });
});
```

```css
.single-gallery{
  width:800px;
  overflow:hidden;
  position:relative;
}
.cycle-slideshow img {
  width:100%;
  height:494px;
  max-width:100%;
}

#single-pager a img {
  width: 49.3px !important;
  height:49.3px !important;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}

#single-pager a.cycle-pager-active img {
  opacity: 0.4;
}

#single-left,
#single-right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 1000;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
  padding: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#single-left {
  left: 0;
}

#single-right {
  right: 0;
}

.filter {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1000;
  right: 0;
  top:0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #FFF;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  padding: 10px 30px;
}

.filter li {
  list-style-type:none;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
  padding: 5px;
}

a[data-hidden="true"]{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lightgallery/latest/css/lightgallery.css'>


<div class="single-gallery" id="single-gallery">
  <div class="single-gallery-carousel">
   <div class="slideshow-area">
        <ul class="filter">
              <li id="sports">Sports</li>
              <li id="naturel">Naturel</li>
              <li id="animals">Animals</li>
              <li id="show-all">All</li>
            </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="mySlideShow">
      <a data-exthumbimage="http://cdn.anitur.com.tr/resimler/normal/2014-02/tur_kuba_CP62I36hoYGMpFFRiN78.jpg" data-id="naturel"  data-hidden="false" data-src="http://cdn.anitur.com.tr/resimler/normal/2014-02/tur_kuba_CP62I36hoYGMpFFRiN78.jpg">
             <img class="lazyload" data-src="https://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightGallery/static/img/12.jpg" data-poster="https://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightGallery/static/img/12.jpg">
          </a> 
          
          <a class="video" data-hidden="false" data-id="naturel" data-src="http://nerdist.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/The-Evolution-of-Pixar.jpg" href="https://vimeo.com/1084537">
            <img class="lazyload" data-src="http://nerdist.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/The-Evolution-of-Pixar.jpg">
          </a> 
          
          <a data-exthumbimage="http://betacontent.anitur.com.tr/web/images/h494/2017-03/otel_aurum-didyma-spa-beach-resort_sReNOBXcinbZI7lNGf3x.jpg" data-hidden="false" data-id="naturel" data-src="http://betacontent.anitur.com.tr/web/images/h494/2017-03/otel_aurum-didyma-spa-beach-resort_sReNOBXcinbZI7lNGf3x.jpg">
            <img class="lazyload" data-src="http://betacontent.anitur.com.tr/web/images/h494/2017-03/otel_aurum-didyma-spa-beach-resort_sReNOBXcinbZI7lNGf3x.jpg" data-poster="http://betacontent.anitur.com.tr/web/images/h494/2017-03/otel_aurum-didyma-spa-beach-resort_sReNOBXcinbZI7lNGf3x.jpg">
          </a> 
          
          <a data-exthumbimage="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/tulips-lightbox.jpg" data-hidden="false" data-id="animals" data-src="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/tulips-lightbox.jpg">
            <img class="lazyload" data-src="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/tulips-lightbox.jpg" data-poster="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/tulips-lightbox.jpg">
            </a> 
          
          <a data-exthumbimage="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/golden-wheat-field-lightbox.jpg" data-hidden="false" data-id="sports" data-src="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/golden-wheat-field-lightbox.jpg">
            <img class="lazyload" data-src="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/golden-wheat-field-lightbox.jpg" data-poster="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/golden-wheat-field-lightbox.jpg" ></a> 
          
          <a data-exthumbimage="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/night-in-the-city-lightbox.jpg" data-hidden="false" data-id="sports" data-src="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/night-in-the-city-lightbox.jpg">
            <img class="lazyload" data-src="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/night-in-the-city-lightbox.jpg" data-poster="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/night-in-the-city-lightbox.jpg" ></a> 
          
          <a data-exthumbimage="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/night-in-the-city-lightbox.jpg" data-hidden="false" data-id="sports" data-src="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/night-in-the-city-lightbox.jpg">
            <img class="lazyload" data-src="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/night-in-the-city-lightbox.jpg" data-poster="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/dandelion-lightbox.jpg" ></a> 
          
          <a data-exthumbimage="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/dandelion-lightbox.jpg" data-hidden="false" data-id="animals" data-src="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/dandelion-lightbox.jpg">
            <img class="lazyload" data-src="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/dandelion-lightbox.jpg" data-poster="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/dandelion-lightbox.jpg" >
          </a> 
          
          <a data-exthumbimage="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/daffodil-flowers-lightbox.jpg" data-hidden="false" data-id="sports" data-src="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/daffodil-flowers-lightbox.jpg">
            <img class="lazyload" data-src="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/daffodil-flowers-lightbox.jpg"  data-poster="https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/7/images/lightbox/daffodil-flowers-lightbox.jpg" >
          </a>
          
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="center external" id="single-pager">
   </div>
  </div>
  <div id="single-next-prev">
   <span class="ani-icon-chevron-pointing-to-the-left ani-cycle-control" id="single-left"></span> <span class="ani-icon-right-chevron ani-cycle-control" id="single-right"></span>
  </div>
 </div>


<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.cycle2/2.1.6/jquery.cycle2.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/lightgallery@1.3.5,lg-fullscreen@1.0.1,lg-hash@1.0.1,lg-pager@1.0.1,lg-share@1.0.1,lg-thumbnail@1.0.1,lg-video@1.0.1,lg-autoplay@1.0.1,lg-zoom@1.0.3'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lazysizes/3.0.0/lazysizes.min.js'></script>
```

Comment: I've never worked with any of these plugins but it seems just a wrong load script order. Check the docs to see which order the scrips should be loaded.

Comment: your given example code is working? where is the error?

Comment: choose any categories on carousel for example: animal than click on any image than see popup is not opening anymore :)

Comment: @ElmerDantas I downloaded it from github and it was latest version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check in your network tab, whether the lightgallery script is getting loaded last or not and you should also call it in last where you are calling scripts.
"$items" is undefined because lightgallery script is getting loaded first and script is not getting proper data.

Comment: where shall I call $items from ? I checkout network tab and it only couldn't find dataexthumbimage but it is about only cycle2 thumbnail..because I'm getting cycle2 thumbnails from exthumbimage